# how to write CASE WHEN query with waterline js

Tags: sails.js, waterline, knex.js, sails-postgresql

how to write `CASE WHEN` query with waterline Model.

```
SELECT  description,order_no,CASE WHEN STATUS=1 THEN 'True' ELSE
'False' END AS STATUS FROM CATEGORY_MAS as category
```

Comment: ModelName.query(QueryString,function(err,results){});
i guess this is what you need

Comment: i know query method but i need readable solution. row sql query is not readable.

Comment: There is no way in waterline since it is impractical to cover all the possible query.But you can try it manually that will be readable for sure.

Answer (score 0):

as par as I know there is no such facilities provided by waterline js in sails js. It is better to fetch data and use if else in your sails controller.